# Replace character in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need replace a character in a string for a backslash,

example

`var string = "hello world!";
string.replace("!","\");`

help me please

thanks!!!!

Comment: string.replace("!","\\");

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
string = string.replace(/!/g, '\\');
```

backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash and better to use regex `/!/` in order to replace all the occurrences of `!`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a dupe, but haven't found the proper dupe ;)

Comment: Probably yes as dup finding isn't very easy here