# How to Convert this < symbol into a &lt; while this symbol is in code

Tags: javascript, html

I am Going To Create two textboxes with height and width of 600px. How i want is like the user enters his code into the first textbox and clicks on change button then the code's only symbols like '<' and '>' are changed into text words like `&lt; and &gt;` but the other code should not be changed.How can I do it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace character in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140777/replace-character-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?  This will lead to broken code somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
 "he<ll><>oooo".replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution:

```
var encodedStr = rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
   return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```

posted by Chris Baker should fix your problem:
[Encode html entities in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: I believe this is the correct answers OP wants, I misread his requirements

Comment: Don't re-post another answer, mark the question as a duplicate.